# php GridView table while row as link

Tags: php, mysql, gridview

I've been searching about what i want and nothing..
If someone knows a tutorial or something like.

What i want is...

I've a got table made in php... and i add a "link to get the id",

```
echo "<td><a href='profile.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Details</a></td>";
```

using the ID from the transaction to show a full details from that ID. in the same page.

My question is...  How can i show that id details... as a new table with that details.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition in your file with that table (I am assuming it is the profile.php file).

If your code looks something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        ...
        echo "<td><a href='profile.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Details</a></td>";
        ...
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
}
```

Just change it this way:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id);

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "User data: <br>";
        echo "Name: ".$row['name']."<br>";
        ...
} else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                ...
                echo "<td><a href='profile.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Details</a></td>";
                ...
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
        }
}
```

Comment: I put it like u said.. But when i click in "Detail" is not showing nothing... Just show the ID number in the URL bar.

Comment: @user353232 - it should work. Did you put in your profile.php file?